XAMPP and phpMyAdmin configuration on Windows: "Access is Denied" error when resetting folder permissions
I'm facing a critical issue while setting up XAMPP on my Windows machine. Specifically, I'm unable to reset permissions for essential directories such as mysql\data, resulting in repeated "Access is denied" errors.
Despite attempting commands like takeown and icacls to grant administrative privileges, these efforts have been unsuccessful due to persistent permission issues. This problem prevents me from configuring XAMPP and accessing phpMyAdmin properly, hindering my ability to develop and manage databases locally.
I need a solution or workaround to resolve these permission conflicts and proceed with setting up XAMPP effectively.

Shouldn't you ask this in superuser, and ask about how to reset the permissions? Doesn't sound like a software development question at all.

I think this qualifies as "software tools commonly used by developers" and thus is on-topic. However there is not much detail to go on here.
